# Which eclipse do I need to install for Cocos2d-x v3.x?

Tags: eclipse, cocos2d-x

I downloaded eclipse installer, and ran it.

There are so many versions of eclipse like

Eclipse for IDE for java developers,
for C/C++ developers
etc

Which one do I need to install?

Comment: Do you want to use the [Cocos2d-x](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/products#cocos2d-x) framework in C++, Lua or JavaScript?

Comment: You should need Eclipse for Java Developers and install a custom Android ADT.